# Ajax Control : CalenderExtender is not working on Production Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-ajax

Creating web application in .Net framework 4.5 using Visual Studio 2013. Install the Ajax Control Toolkit 15.1.3 from NuGate Packages to visual studio 2013. My Pages contains several calender extenders. code is as follows:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtExpectedDate" runat="server" CssClass="input" MaxLength="500" Width="72%" ValidationGroup="BusTravel"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Image ID="imgExpectDate" runat="server" CssClass="CalendarBtn" ImageAlign="Top" ImageUrl="~/PL/images/calendar_view_month.png"/>
<ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender3" runat="server" Format="MM/dd/yyyy" PopupButtonID="imgExpectDate" TargetControlID="txtExpectedDate" Enabled="true" Animated="true" EnabledOnClient="true" EnableViewState="true" FirstDayOfWeek="Default"/>
```

My pages loads fine on server side but can not pop out the calender control to page on server while debugging and starting the application it works fine. after publishing the website and hosting it on server calender controls are not working.

Comment: Does developer console show any error?

Comment: No. Developer console does not show any error. It works fine.